KivyMD MDButton - ImportError
¿cómo andan? Tal parece que kivyMD no quiere que lo aprenda. Después de solucionar (o no) un problema de instalación, estoy intentando practicar con kivyMD para hacer aplicaciones sencillas (como una calculadora). El problema es que ahora no me reconoce la clase MDButton, la cual si figura entre los archivos. Pensando que puede ser un error en el código, copié y pegué el que figura en la página de kivyMD (https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/), pero sigo con el mismo problema. El código es:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDButton, MDButtonIcon, MDButtonText
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return (
            MDScreen(
                MDButton(
                    MDButtonIcon(
                        icon="plus",
                    ),
                    MDButtonText(
                        text="Elevated",
                    ),
                    style="elevated",
                    pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
                ),
                md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.surfaceColor,
            )
        )


Example().run()

Y el error que me arroja es:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Kivy.md\Myquizlet\intento.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivymd.uix.button import MDButton, MDButtonIcon, MDButtonText
 ImportError: cannot import name 'MDButton' from 'kivymd.uix.button' (C:\Kivy.md\virt\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button\__init__.py). Did you mean: 'button'? 

Una alacaración que no figura en el código que se muestra abajo. Uso VSCode. Cuando importo algo como en las primereas líneas, cuando no hay problema lo importado figura en verde. En el caso de que no lo encuentre, como acá, figura en blanco. (si quieren, subo una oto de lo que quiero decir)
¿Alguna idea?
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Otra aclaración: estoy usando kivy 2.0.0

Aparentemente es un problema con kivyMD 2.0.0. Mañana voy a ver en github a ver qué puedo averiguar.
